# JS inserting substr(1) into a var

Tags: javascript, substr

From an open code I have this line

```
var average = parseFloat($(this).attr('id').split('_')[0]),
```

It gets the first part of a div id with '_' as delimiter. The problem is that an id cannot start with a number (naming violation convention). So I am going to add a letter before the id  value in my php script. How do I insert substr(1) to this var to remove this letter and get 'average' as expected?

Comment: So what's the format of the ID now? And how do you want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about this format for an id:

```
<div id="A1000_bc"></div>
```

You can insert the `substr(1)` like this:

```
var average = parseFloat(this.id.split('_')[0].substr(1));
```

I might prefer to do it like this so it's a little less presumptious about the exact format and just grabs the first floating point numeric sequence:

```
var average = parseFloat(this.id.match(/[\d\.\+\-]+/)[0]);
```

Also, notice how I removed the jQuery.  `$(this).attr("id")` performs a lot worse than `this.id` and offers no advantages here.  jQuery should be used only when it's actually better than plain JS.

Both of these methods assume you are only going to present the code with properly formatted ids.  If you want to handle a default condition when the id is not in the right format, then you will need multiple lines of code with some `if` conditions to check for validity and offer a default result when not valid.

Both options work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/B4Rga/

Incidentally, if you control the HTML here, then there are better places to put data like this than in an id.  I'd suggest a custom data attribute (HTML5 standard, but works everywhere).

```
<div id="whatever" data-avg="3.5"></div>
```

Then, you can get the data like this without having to parse it:

```
var average = parseFloat(this.getAttribute("data-avg"));
```

Comment: I could not get it work. The script is from http://myjqueryplugins.com/jRating It gets from<div id="3.5_5634"></div> the average rating 3.5 of the item #5634. I added a "W" so id="W3.5_5634"> and then changed the JS line but the result wasn't correct

Comment: @dstonek - The concept works as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/B4Rga/ so you'll have to show your whole code for us to know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @dstonek - I added a third option to my answer that might be even better.

Comment: Very nice, the first one works as expected. My dumb fault: I had changed the original JS but while the script loads the minified version. Now I go to test your last suggestion. Many thanks.

Answer (score -3):

```
var average = parseFloat(
        $(this)     // you've got a jQuery object here - bad place
        .attr('id') // you've got a string here - why not
        .split('_') // you've got an array here - bad idea
        [0]         // you've got a string here - why not
        // you need to have a number string here 
    );
```

Remeber: `substr(1)` can only be called on Strings.

Comment: Was that supposed to be an answer?